# Unable to save image to the static folder - Heroku / NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, heroku, puppeteer

I've a `node.js` app running with `express` and using `puppeteer` module. The app is working locally with total efficiency but when I upload it to `heroku`, I can't get an image to be saved to the `static` directory.

the line which I use to save file:

```js
async doSomething()=> {
    ....
    await page.screenshot({ path: "public/images/insta.png" })
    ....
}
```

Executing this line in `Heroku` causes this Error:

```
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713334+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/images/insta.png'
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713350+00:00 app[web.1]: -- ASYNC --
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713350+00:00 app[web.1]: at Page.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:116:19)
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713351+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.scrapeProduct (/app/scrapper.js:9:20)
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713351+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713352+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -2,
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713352+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ENOENT',
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713353+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'open',
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713353+00:00 app[web.1]: path: 'public/images/insta.png'
2020-06-25T21:31:02.713353+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I tried to change the path to `"/images/insta.png"`, `__dirname + "/public/images/insta.png"` and other workarounds but none of these worked. The same error is still appearing.

There's a screenshot of my directory:

[image: Screenshot of directory tree]

**Note:** This error doesn't appear while running on localhost &
I have `puppeteer` buildpack installed on my `heroku` slug.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```js
var path = require("path");
var imagePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/images/insta.png');

async doSomething()=> {
    ....
    await page.screenshot({ path: imagePath })
    ....
}
```

It should work that way.

Comment: The same error message is still there:
```log
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/public/images/insta.png'
-- ASYNC --
at Page.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:116:19)
at Object.scrapeProduct (/app/scrapper.js:13:20)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/app/public/images/insta.png'
}
```